# flutter got error code. _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Update context

Can I use where and orderby in FirebaseFirestore to running? Because I got the error in `itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length` when I use this code on below...

[image]

```
body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Posts')
            .where('country', isEqualTo: '${user.country}')
            //.where('country', isEqualTo: 'Australia')
            .orderBy('time', descending: true) 
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context,
            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: width > webScreenSize ? width * 0.3 : 0,
                  vertical: width > webScreenSize ? 15 : 0),
              child: PostCard(
                snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

So...where has problem? when I mark the `.where('country', isEqualTo: '${user.country}')` it's working, but can't use both...

Update context

When I want to get data from firebase, I tried to used this methods, but I get a error code `_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)`.

```
User get getUser => _user!;
```

[image]

If I mark `.where('country', isEqualTo: '${user.country}')` or `.orderBy('time', descending: true)`, it was working, but they can't appear at the same time.

So how can do use both?

```
class _FeedScreenState extends State<FeedScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final User user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;
    return Scaffold(
body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Posts')
            .where('country', isEqualTo: '${user.country}')
            .orderBy('time', descending: true)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context,
            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: width > webScreenSize ? width * 0.3 : 0,
                  vertical: width > webScreenSize ? 15 : 0),
              child: PostCard(
                snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

UserProvider.dart

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  User? _user;
  final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods();

  User get getUser => _user!;

  Future<void> refreshUser() async {
    User user = await _authMethods.getUserDetails();
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: The error indicates that `user` is `null`, so calling `!` on it is an error.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen There must be users, because you must be logged in to view the information

Comment: Where are you initializing `_user`?

Comment: The error message is quite explicit: `_user` is null. If you doubt that it's correct, set a breakpoint on that line and run it in the debugger to check the value.

Comment: @Franknike I'd updated my context.

Comment: You should run refreshUser() first so it sets the value of _user.

Comment: @Franknike Sorry, I dont understand, so how can I do?

Comment: @Franknike I'd refreshUser in user_provider.dart, but still get error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not updating `_user`.

You need to call
`Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).refreshUser()` at least i think that's  how you use provider.

So it should be

```dart
    final width =  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).refreshUser();
    final User user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;
```

That should update/set the value of `_user`

Comment: I'd tried add `Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).refreshUser();`. But still same problem....

Comment: If it's exactly the same error i doubt your `refreshUser()` is work as it should.

Comment: I think it was working because if I add `Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).refreshUser();` into my feed.dart, the screen will keep refreshing... But whne I remark `.where('country', isEqualTo: '${user.country}')`  it was got error

Comment: What's the error message

Comment: I'd found the problem, but I have a new problem and I updated my context. I can't use `where` and `orderby` in FirebaseFirestore`, when I used both i will got error

Comment: Well, that's another question. You should create another question with the error log as this screenshot is just a small piece of the error.
Yes, you can use `orderby` and `where` together